# LESS variable concatenation and interpolation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, mixins

I'm attempting to override Bootstrap's hover effect on the buttons. I'd like to save some space and do it the slick way by simply passing into a mixin the name of a class and have that class' background variable be automatically deduced from just that. So my mixin is:

```
.btn-hover(@name){
  .@{name}:hover{
      background: lighten( @~"@{name}-bg", 10% );
   }
}

.btn-hover(btn-primary);
```

But I can't seem to access the variable `@btn-primary-bg` by concatenating `-bg` to `btn-primary`, because `@~"@{btn-name}-bg"` results in a compiler error. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? It would be pretty slick if it were.

Edit -----------------------------------------------------------------

Just stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325381/all-buttons-hover-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap) and it's definitely related, but I think my question really just boils down to:

**In LESS, can you access a variable via interpolation after string concatenation?**

```
@btn-success-bg: #00ff00;
@name: btn-success;
@background: @~"@{name}-bg";  // How do I access @btn-success-bg?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
   @btn-primary-bg: red;

    .btn-hover(@name){
      .@{name}:hover{
          @buttonname: ~"@{name}-bg";
          background: lighten( @@buttonname, 10% );
       }
    }

    .btn-hover(btn-primary);
```

Also see: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names

Comment: Just in case you don't need `~` for `@buttonname` value, `@@` perfectly works with quoted strings.

Comment: So my mistake was really that I just needed to store the value of `~"@{name}-bg"` in a variable first, and then access it like `@@value`?

Comment: yes, indeed and as mentioned by @seven-phases-max the tilde `~` is not needed too.